# Modifying a Serializable class and reading an old generation of data for .NET

Tags: .net, serialization

I have a struct that is currently defined as

```
[Serializable]
public struct PointMap
{
    public PointMap( double point, double distance )
    {
        Point = point;
        Distance = distance;
    }

    public double Point;
    public double Distance;
}
```

I want to modify it to now be a class, implement ISerializableObject, add a label, and still be able to read data saved as the struct above.  So, something like this.

```
[Serializable]
public class PointMap : ISerializable
{
    public PointMap( double point, double distance )
    {
        Point = point;
        Distance = distance;
    }

    public void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
    {
        ...
    }

    private string _label;
    public double Point;
    public double Distance;
}
```

Now, is it possible to write something that will understand the old serialization objects either in `GetObjectData()` or someway to map the old version of the class to a custom deserializer? 
We're using .NET 4.0.